# Polygon inside polygon inside polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I have number of simple polygons which do not intersect each other but some polygons may be embedded into others.

For example:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                            |
|   +----------------+          +--------+   |
|   |                |         /         |   |
|   |   +--------+   |        /          |   |
|   |   |        |   |       /  +----(2)-+   |
|   |   |        |   |      /   |            |
|   |   +----(3)-+   |     /    |   +---+    |
|   |                |    +-----+   |   |    |
|   +------------(2)-+              +(2)+    |
|                                            |
+----------------------------------------(1)-+
```

How to find out the "depth" of all the polygons? In other words, how to find out by how many polygons a polygon is encompassed by? The "depth" are the numbers in parentheses.

I could count how many times a point of a polygon is inside of all the other polygons but this has quadratic complexity. How to compute those depths faster?

Comment: [[v1, v2, v3], [v4, v5, v6, v7], [v8, v9, ... - basically a flat list, without any tree-like structure, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @EcirHana by simple polygons do you actually mean simple polygons or do you mean rectangular axis-aligned simple polygons ?

Comment: @mmgp: I mean any kind of simple polygons.

Comment: @EcirHana this is handled by the paper "Polygon Nesting and Robustness", I might include a answer later if no one gives it earlier.

Comment: If you need to know the depth of a given polygon P, and you have a point O garanteed to be outside (of every polygons), perhaps counting the number of polygons uniquely intersected by the segment between O and the vertex of P closest to O could work.

Comment: Are the shapes actually polygons or are they rectangles? Algorithm simplifies greatly if you use rectangles.

Comment: @MC: I mean any kind of simple polygons.

Comment: @mmgp: thanks, the paper looks very good but there is no code. Please, by chance, don't you have some code? Or at least a detailed pseudocode?

Comment: It looks like what you are looking for is the winding number (because we can consider all those polygons as one big self-overlapping polygon): http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html ?

Comment: @SamuelAudet: thanks but I don't quite understand what you mean - how do I pick "P"? And do I have to calculate the winding number of all the vertices?

Comment: Pick one of the endpoints and ideally use simulation of simplicity as explained on this page http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html ... I could try to provide an answer if this sounds like what you need

Comment: @SamuelAudet I would be thankful for an answer, of course. But I don't understand what you are proposing so I don't know if it sounds like what I'm after. How is it different than to "count how many times a point of a polygon is inside of all the other polygons"? Can you make an estimation of its complexity? In other words, if I get that "depth" numbers in better than quadratic time in worst case, then yes please, post it below.

Comment: Hum, I guess it is pretty much what you explain in your question. We can use an algorithm like [_plane sweep_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) to bring it down to something like `O(n log n)`, but yeah this is getting complicated...

Comment: @SamuelAudet could you please explain to me how to use the line sweep to bring the time down to O(nlogn)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23196/discussion-between-samuel-audet-and-ecir-hana)

Answer (score 2):

Put your polygons into some kind of [spatial lookup structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database), for example an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) based on the minimum bounding rectangles for the polygons. Then you should be able to compute the containment relation that you're after in O(*n* log *n*). (Unless you're in a pathological case where many of the minimum bounding rectangles for your polygons overlap, which seems unlikely based on your description.)

Edited to add: of course, you don't rely on the R-tree to tell you if one polygon is inside another (it's based on minimum bounding rectangles so it can only give you an approximation). You use the R-tree to cheaply identify *candidate inclusions* which you then verify in the expensive way (checking that a point in one polygon is inside the other).

Comment: This is a very simplistic approach that doesn't need pathological cases at all to fail. Suppose there is a large polygon shaped like a "C", if we put a square in the free empty area of "C", why would you say that this square is contained by the other polygon ? Or maybe this is the pathological case and I'm adding unneeded requirements to a question that isn't mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think it will work. The problem is the time needed to build the lookup structure as it wont be reused again (i.e. the polygons may be different every time). Also, bboxes may or may not overlap, that's 50% and that's a lot :).

Comment: It costs O(n log n) to build the R-tree, so I don't think that's a concern.

Comment: @EcirHana this will work, building up an spatial index can be extremly fast, i recommend using an PMR bucket Rectangle quadtree as spatial index.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you depict a non-convex polygon so the rtree approach that others suggested will not be effective by itself. But you could couple that with an additional check to see if a vertex of the polygon is inside the other whenever the you find a match with the rtree approach. This would reduce the number of times you have to do the "point in polygon" check.

Another approach is to take your first idea - i.e. to check a vertex of each polygon with everyother polygon - and modify it to cache the results that you already computed and reuse them to reduce time complexity. The approach desribed below essentially builds a tree structure out of the polygons themselves, rather than use an rtree. Its essentially a different tree structure that honors non-convex polygons.

1. Initially each polygon is a root node and in a tree of its own.
2. You have to loop through your set of root nodes and check if its inside another root node using the "point in polygon" test.
3. When you find a match, remove the smaller polygon from the set of root nodes and add it as a child node to the bigger polygon. You started building a meaningful tree structure and you are also reducing the size of the container you are iterating over (root nodes) so the future iterations will be faster.
4. Continue this until the number of root nodes stops changing.
5. Remember in the main nested loop you are only comparing if one root node is inside another. When you find a match (small node inside a big node) you can skip the subtree of the smaller node. But you do have to traverse the subtree of the bigger node and do the checks to find the right place for the smaller node in the hierarchy. But still you avoid a lot of checks compared to a simple nested loop with quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

(This approach follows a similar idea to @GarethRees 's: first, cheaply discover which pairs of polygons you don't need to check for inclusion. Once the number of pairs still needed to check is acceptable, do the exact (expensive) geometric check.)

It's easy to calculate for each polygon p the bounding rectangle, i.e. the left, right, top and bottom, so let's do that first. E.g. for left: `p.L = min { x : (x,y) is a vertex of p }` Time is linear in the number of points.

To avoid having to compare each polygon to each other one, you could divide up the area into a 2x2 grid. Suppose the width and height of the area are respectively given by `Dx` and `Dy`, then you can create nine sets `top,bottom,left,right,topright,topleft,bottomright,bottomleft,rest` and do the following:

```
for p in polygons:
    in_top    = p.B > Dy/2
    in_bottom = p.T < Dy/2
    in_left   = p.R < Dx/2
    in_right  = p.L > Dx/2 
    if in_top:
        if in_left:
            add p to topleft
        elsif in_right:
            add p to topright
        else:
            add p to top
    elsif in_bottom:
        if in_left:
            add p to bottomleft
        elsif in_right:
            add p to bottomright
        else:
            add p to bottom

    if in_right and not (in_top or in_bottom):
        add p to right
    elsif in_left and not (in_top or in_bottom):
        add p to left

    if not (in_top or in_bottom or in_left or in_right):
        add p to rest
```

This is again linear time. Each polygon has been binned into its most "tightly" containing sector. What have you gained by this? Well, you know for example that for any polygon `p` in `left` there can't possibly be any inclusion relationship with set `right`, so you don't need to compare them. Likewise between `bottomleft` and `right`, `bottomleft` and `topleft`, and so on. Here is what it would look like on your example:

```
                      Dx/2
+----------------------|---------------------+
|                      |                     |
|   +----------------+ |        +--------+   |
|   |                | |       /         |   |
|   |   +--------+   | |      /          |   |
|___|___|________|___|_|____ /__+===d(2)=+___|_ Dy/2
|   |   |        |   | |    /   |            |
|   |   +---b(3)-+   | |   /    |   +---+    |
|   |                | |  +-----+   |   |    |
|   +-----------c(2)-+ |            e(2)+    |
|                      |                     |
+----------------------|----------------a(1)-+
```

So `rest = {a}, top = {}, bottom = {}, left = {b,c}, right = {d}`

`topleft = {}, topright = {}, bottomleft = {}, bottomright = {e}`

So basically now you need to compare (with the expensive exact check) at most `b` to `c`, `d` to `e`, and `a` to all others -- in fact, if you order the checks in a clever way, you won't need to compare `a` to all others, because inclusion is transitive, so if you notice that `c` includes `b`, and `a` includes `c`, then you do not need to check if `a` includes `b`.

Another point is that you can apply the above reasoning recursively. Say for example the set `topright` is too big for your taste; you can then apply the same technique by further dividing up that subregion (just need to get the book-keeping right).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately, I'm really interested in those "expensive exact" checks. I'm aware that I could use spatial hashing, bounding boxes or bounding hierarchies but as far as I understand none of them speeds up the worst case. The paper "Polygon Nesting and Robustness" mentioned above by @mmgp seems to be closest to the right approach but it's a bit difficult to transform it to working code.

Comment: before you do, what complexity do they have?

Comment: @EcirHana : the number of vertices of polygon 1 times the number of vertices of polygon 2.

Comment: Divided by two, yes. This is what I propose in the question myself and would like to improve on it.

Comment: @EcirHana : as far as I understand it, you propose to check each pair of *polygons*, i.e. something quadratic in the number of polygons. I propose to first get rid of many such pairs by simple linear-time heuristics, and then for all cases we did not eliminate, do an exact check, which is quadratic in the number of *vertices of the remaining polygons*. Let me know if you agree.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23580/discussion-between-ecir-hana-and-mitchus)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you get get away with sorting the polygons, using a test of whether one is inside another as the comparison operator.

## Step 1

Suppose we define the relation '<' between polygons as follows: A < B iff A is inside B.
It so happens that if A < B and B < C, then A < C (i.e. if polygon A is inside B and B is inside C, then A must be inside C). Now, we have a strict weak ordering between arbitrary polygons.

[Edit: You'd need to use some sort of point-inside-non-convex-polygon test, but presumably you are doing that already.]

## Step 2

Sort the polygons according to this comparison using your favorite comparison-based sorting algorithm. For instance, merge sort has a worst-case time complexity of O(nlogn) comparisons where n is the number of polygons.

[Edit: This is the important step, because it gets rid of the quadratic complexity.]

## Step 3

Ensure that the "largest" (i.e. outermost) element is first on your sorted array of polygons. (Reverse the list if necessary to achieve this - it is linear on the number of polygons).

## Step 4

Now the "largest" (i.e. outermost) polygon should be the first element.

[Edit: 
In fact, the polygons have been sorted according to their depth. However, two polygons that have the same depth may appear in different orders depending on whether the sort was stable. This doesn't matter to us; what we are interested in is the **change** in depth.]

We will now assign a depth to each polygon as follows. 
Firstly, initialize the depth of each one to 0 ([Edit: initialize to 1, according to the example]). Next, iterate through your sorted list, but this time compare each element p only to the next element p+1. If (p+1 < p) is true, then increment the depth of p+1. Else, set the depth of p+1 to be the same as the depth of p.

Comment: What if none of the polygons is nested? I.e., what if all of the polygons are "outermost"?

Comment: Then under any order, they would be considered sorted, and they would all have a depth of 0 since every comparison `<` will return false. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Also, just realized your "outermost" depth should be 1 (according to your example). This is achieved by initializing the depth to 1 instead of 0 in Step 4.

Comment: What I try to say is that sorting performs n log n comparisons and each comparison has linear complexity. So it's O(n n log n) - worse than the naive version from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Orient your polygons in the same direction, say counter-clockwise.

Step 2: For any point (x, y) for which you need to compute the "depth" for compute the total winding number. This can be done in a number of ways; the fastest one in practice is to compute the SIGNED number of intersections between the horizontal (or vertical) ray originating in (x, y).

In particular, the depth for each polygon would be the depth of any of its vertices.

Comment: Step 2 has linear complexity and I have to repeat it for all the polygons so it has the same quadratic complexity as the original approach above.